# Is it possible to run openoffice macro from external file?

Tags: file, macros, external, openoffice.org, execution

I want to run OpenOffice macro from external file. Like:

```
vlad@leo ~ $ soffice macro:///home/vlad/q.vbs
```

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer - just a comment instead, so as to bump this question, and hopefully get an answer :)

This possibly has to do with having to explicitly set permissions for macros, for instance:

[Can't execute macro from command line (View topic) • OpenOffice.org Community Forum](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8232)

> Edit: In fact it seems to be impossible to call document macros, which is perfect for security reasons.

See also:

- [Custom OpenOffice.org Basic Macros and Libraries - OpenOffice.org Wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/Using_Custom_Macros_and_Libraries)
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: Enable OpenOffice Macro through Command Line](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=37562).
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: simple command line question](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=2619)
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: HowTo Run Macros from Document from Shell](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=6808)

As a side note, the standard `Module1` file can be found in (on Linux):

```
~/.openoffice.org/3/user/basic/Standard/Module1.xba
~/.libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard/Module1.xba
```

and note that the .xba is actually an XML file, that contains the Basic macro source, as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE script:module PUBLIC "-//OpenOffice.org//DTD OfficeDocument 1.0//EN" "module.dtd">
<script:module xmlns:script="http://openoffice.org/2000/script" script:name="Module1" script:language="StarBasic">REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main

End Sub</script:module>
```

Unfortunately, just copying to the respective directories (below, in extensions) does not work, as in the following command line snippet..

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/mytest
sudo cp ~/.libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard/Module1.xba /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/mytest/MyTestModule.xba
sudo sed -i 's/Module1/MyTestModule/g' /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/mytest/MyTestModule.xba
```

So I guess the only way is to manually add/allow Macros in OpenOffice, and then possibly find where the respective .xba's are stored, and change their code there (if only a command line usage is desired)...

Maybe using [Python - OpenOffice.org Wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) is more open approach to external scripts - but it requires that you start openoffice as a server...

Comment: Yes. I have prepared ERB template for xba file and write it to `~/.openoffice.org/3/user/basic/Lib/Statements.xba`

but also i have updated 

`~/.openoffice.org/3/user/basic/Lib/script.xlb` and `~/.openoffice.org/3/user/basic/script.xlc`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Vlad, good to have those files listed... btw, never heard of ERB templates, I guess it is this [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.html), to read later :) Cheers!

Comment: just a note, in newer versions `~/.libreoffice/` is `~/.config/libreoffice/`