# Open Office server mode macro

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm trying to run xls files on an open office server on Windows.

I start the oo in server mode with the following bat:

```
start soffice.exe -headless -nofirststartwizard
-accept="socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service"
```

The server is used by a Java application.

The problem is that the macros of the given xls file don't execute.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Please add more code, on how you are passing the XLS to soffice server, and also you version of soffice might be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Taking some links from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238845/450812

> This possibly has to do with having to explicitly set permissions for
>   macros, for instance:

[Can't execute macro from command line (View topic) • OpenOffice.org Community Forum](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8232)

See also:

- [Custom OpenOffice.org Basic Macros and Libraries - OpenOffice.org Wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/Using_Custom_Macros_and_Libraries)
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: Enable OpenOffice Macro through Command Line](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=37562).
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: simple command line question](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=2619)
- [OpenOffice.org Forum :: HowTo Run Macros from Document from Shell](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=6808)